Can't login with Active Directory credentials on Ubuntu GUI mode (Failed to start session)
I have Windows Server 2022 and Ubuntu Server 24.04. Ubuntu Server is joined to Windows Server successfully, but I can't login to GUI on Ubuntu Server.
In terminal all work`s fine and I can login with credentials from Active Directory.
After logging in to the terminal, I get:
john@mydomain.tld@ubuntu-server:~$
So, it`s correct.
But when I entered credentials from AD on GUI login screen, I get an error:
"Failed to start session"

This is the content of the "auth.log" file (/var/log/auth.log)
ubuntu-server lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "john@mydomain.tld"
ubuntu-server lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:1 ruser= rhost=  user=john@mydomain.tld
ubuntu-server lightdm: pam_sss(lightdm:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:1 ruser= rhost= user=john@mydomain.tld

I follow this steps and everything seems to be working fine... (But I can`t login with GUI session, only in Terminal environment…)
Link on ubuntu.com docs
Question: How can I log in to the Ubuntu GUI with credentials from AD???
P.S. I`m using XFCE with lightdm manager. Thanks in advance for any help in resolving this issue!
